# Can we customize select option form?

Tags: html, css, forms

Is it possible to customize the select option form? I want to customize the dropdown. Like changing the background color.

Code from w3schools:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Definitely yes, try i.e, adding a new css class like: `#cars { background-color: red }`

Comment: Sadly its not working. I need to customize the dropdown items.

Comment: Try adding styles by tag then `#cars > option {background-color: red;}`

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do so, although it will require some JavaScript.

In your HTML, create the `select` element as you would usually do, and enclose it inside a `div`. The `select` element will contain the actual `options` that you want to be displayed, while the `div` will be targetted by JavaScript to create your custom `select` which can be customized with CSS afterward. W3C offers a [really good example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp) with the required HTML, CSS, and JS.

While the previous gives you more control and customization, here is [an alternative](https://moderncss.dev/custom-select-styles-with-pure-css/) with no JavaScript whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo" style="background-color:red;">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab" style="background-color:blue;">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel" style="background-color:yellow;">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to your select

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select class="customselect" name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Add use css . selector

```
.customselect{
  background-color: green;
}
```

You can see documentation about select css properties [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp)